# Loading shared libraries using ctypes on android

Tags: python, android, linux, ctypes, buildozer

I am currently working on porting a python application that uses audio to android. The application originally ran on linux and uses libportaudio.so as its audio library. In python I'm using ctypes to load the library and I am creating the apk using buildozer.

This fine gentleman created a libportaudio.so that is compiled for ARM which is available here:
https://github.com/Gundersanne/portaudio_opensles
I have tried out some of his example programs so I know that his library works on my phone; however, I have not seen anyone use it with python and ctypes.

The problem comes when I try to load the library in my python program as follows:
`ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libportaudio.so')`
I get the following error:

```
09-28 18:52:31.345 20495 20727 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
09-28 18:52:31.345 20495 20727 I python  :    File "/home/robo1340/Desktop/projectx/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 99, in <module>
09-28 18:52:31.345 20495 20727 I python  :    File "/home/robo1340/Desktop/projectx/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
09-28 18:52:31.346 20495 20727 I python  :    File "/home/robo1340/Desktop/projectx/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
09-28 18:52:31.346 20495 20727 I python  :  OSError: dlopen failed: library "libportaudio.so" not found
09-28 18:52:31.346 20495 20727 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Note that I have added libportaudio.so in my main project folder and added .so to my included extensions in the buildozer.spec file as follows:
`source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ini,so`

Additionally, I opened up an adb shell to confirm that libportaudio.so was copied to my phone. The file is there.

Here is where things get interesting.

I decided to pass an absolute path into the LoadLibrary call as follows:
`ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/data/data/com.projectx.main/files/app/libportaudio.so')`

Alas, that fixed the initial problem, but then I immediately run into a different one.

```
09-28 18:57:56.988 21267 21532 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
09-28 18:57:56.988 21267 21532 I python  :    File "/home/robo1340/Desktop/projectx/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 97, in <module>
09-28 18:57:56.988 21267 21532 I python  :    File "/home/robo1340/Desktop/projectx/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
09-28 18:57:56.989 21267 21532 I python  :    File "/home/robo1340/Desktop/projectx/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
09-28 18:57:56.989 21267 21532 I python  :  OSError: dlopen failed: library "libgnustl_shared.so" not found
09-28 18:57:56.989 21267 21532 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

It seems that somewhere in the ctypes library itself, it tries to load another shared library and is unable to find it. This is where I run out of ideas. Is there something I'm missing in the buildozer.spec file? Or do I need to find this libgnustl_shared.so library and manually add it to my project? Is it even practical to try to use ctypes on android this way?

Comment: Well looks like I may have solved my own problem. I found a version of libgnustl_shared.so compiled for ARM and loaded it first as follows:


   **cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))**

   **ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(cwd, 'libgnustl_shared.so'))**

   **ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(cwd, 'libportaudio.so'))**

I also found a better way to specify the absolute path. After that everything loads and works more or less as expected. I'm not sure why though, I'll take a lucky break when I can get one though.